# Eclipse Class File Metadata

Tags: java, android, eclipse, decompiler

In Visual Studio, I can obtain a succinct list of public methods/members exposed in a class for which I do not have the source (i.e. bundled inside a DLL) by pressing F12 (GoToDefinition).

Similarly, I am learning the Android API - in Eclipse. Jumping to an Android framework method definition produces decompilation output which is not intuitive to read, and is very verbose. To mimic results like Visual Studio, I am considering several options:

1. How can I format the decompilation output to be 'cleaner' - I have looked through Eclipse's preferences menus and have not found a way to do this.
2. How do I 'add corresponding source files' once Google provides it, so that jumping to definition yields the actual definition?
3. Is there a plugin that does this already? I looked into Jadclipse, but that project has not been updated in several years, and is still a decompiler.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could try http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html - it's a "little nicer" than the internal Eclipse decompilation.
2. When opening a class definition for class without source available, you should see a button "Attach Source" at the top of the decompilation output where you can associate the corresponding source files.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can view the .class files outline using the Outline view

Comment: This is analogous to expanding the class under Package Explorer view, and it opens an editor window with .class/decompilation. I am interested if there is something to replace this editor completely.

Answer (score 0):

I found another decompiler that nicely integrates with Eclipse:

**http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse**