# Eclipse .class outline viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, .class-file

I am used to work on Visual Studio for C# coding 
and eclipse for Java coding. Though my experience with eclipse
is very positive, I lack the nice and welcoming text file 
that VS generates for IL classes without source attached (third-party or not in solution).

I need sometimes to browse just the signature ("header") of the java .class
file (included javadoc would be nice too), and in most of the time
I'm not interested in decompiled java bytecode.

Is there a plugin that does that? 
I looked at [Bytecode Outline](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html) referenced here at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986772/eclipse-class-file-metadata)
but that's still not the thing I'm looking for.
I really need to click on a class file or go to type declaration
and be able to see the class outline at the main editor window
with javadoc if available.

Thanks!

Comment: Funny... I once wanted the exact opposite in Eclipse: see the decompiled bytecode for a class that does have source attached :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have jar that includes the class files you can just add it to the project classpath `Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add JARs...`. After this you can browse the method signatures in the `Project Explorer` inside `Referenced Libraries`.

You might be able to do this for a class file directly, but at least you can just wrap it into a jar to do this.